# Determine whether the following set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Being pretty new to Linear Algebra, I am trying find whether the set given is a Vector Space or not:
\begin{equation*}
V = \{A\in M_{3\times3} : AA^{t} = -I\}.
\end{equation*}
I've tried to solve it and I saw that it's a vector space. However my answer is incorrect and I cannot understand why. I understand what a vector space is but I don't seem to be able to solve such trivial questions.

Could anyone please give me a detailed answer on how to work out such problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your work?  Then, we can identify the error.

Comment: Hint: What is the zero vector of $M_{3\times 3}$?  Does it satisfy the conditions?

Comment: What are the axioms for a vector space?

Comment: @MichaelBurr No, it doesn't. I kind of understand what you mean here. But the thing that I want to understand is, how that set is interpreted? It says that A is a 3x3 matrix such that $AA^{t} = -I$ Does that mean I have a set of 3x3 matrices, including the 0 matrix and thus it should obey the rules of algebra for it to work? I can't seem to be able to visualise the set.

Comment: $V$ is the collection of all $3\times 3$ matrices $A$ that satisfy the conditions $AA^t=-I$.  Now, the vector space operation on $3\times 3$ matrices is matrix addition, so we must use that operation here.

Any matrix that satisfies the equation $AA^t=-I$ is in the set (but it is not easy to figure out which matrices satisfy this condition).  Since the zero matrix doesn't satisfy the condition, it isn't in the set, so the set isn't a vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be since the zero matrix does not belong to this set.